# AccessViolationException was unhandled accessing a printer's scanner

Tags: c#, access-violation

I've read a lot of different posts for the past couple hours about this exception but have not found a solution for my problem. The hard part is im using a library i found to access a printers scanner so a lot of it is foreign code to me. The part that really gets me is the code was working yesterday and now today after changing absolutely nothing this started happening. The error is not random and is always on this line of code here.

```
rc = DSMident(appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Identity, TwMSG.CloseDS, srcds);
```

in this method

```
public void CloseSrc()
    {
        TwRC rc;
        if (srcds.Id != IntPtr.Zero)
        {            
            TwUserInterface guif = new TwUserInterface();
            rc = DSuserif(appid, srcds, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.UserInterface, TwMSG.DisableDS, guif);
            rc = DSMident(appid, IntPtr.Zero, TwDG.Control, TwDAT.Identity, TwMSG.CloseDS, srcds);                           
        }
    }
```

im sorry this is so vague and if you need any other information or code please let me know! thank you!

Comment: Put delay between call to `DSuserif` and `DSMident` function calls. Sounds something suspicious there to me.

Comment: a delay as in a time delay? how long and what information will that give me?

Comment: You can use `Thread.Sleep(1000)` with delay of 1 seconds. As you said it was working all fine hence there could be timings issue.

Comment: how would i have the thread wait 1 second if that method is in a library? says the thread does not exist in the current context.

Comment: ok i did this System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); to wait 5 seconds and it still had the same error